# Acumatica custom field SOLine transferred to ARTran

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to propogate a custom field value on the line of a sales order (SOLine) to the sales invoice (ARTran).  I've looked at other examples but can't get the code to work...see below:

```
using PX.Objects.SO;

namespace PX.Objects.SO
{

public class SOInvoiceEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension<SOInvoiceEntry>
{

#region Event Handlers
public delegate void InvoiceCreatedDelegate(ARInvoice invoice, SOOrder 
source);
[PXOverride]
public void InvoiceCreated(ARInvoice invoice, SOOrder source, 
InvoiceCreatedDelegate baseMethod)
{
  baseMethod(invoice,source);

ARTran.RowInserted.AddHandler<ARTran>((cache, args) =>
{
var arTran = (ARTran)args.Row;

ARTranExt arTranExt = PXCache<ARTran>.GetExtension<ARTranExt>(arTran);
SOLineExt soLineExt = PXCache<SOLine>.GetExtension<SOLineExt>(soLine);
arTranExt.UsrContactID = soLineExt.UsrContactID;
});

}




#endregion

}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to put the handler on the graph which creates the ARTran, ARInvoiceEntry:

```
PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<ARInvoiceEntry>((graph) =>
{
    graph.RowInserting.AddHandler<ARTran>((sender, e) =>
    {
    }
}
```

The way you have it setup it will catch the event on the SOInvoiceEntry graph which is not the one inserting the ARTran lines, ARInvoiceEntry is the one insterting the lines.

InvoiceCreated is probably not the right place to put it though. Usually I put the event hook right before calling the CreateInvoice Action.

The sequence is:

1. With InstanceCreated you add the hook to any graph of generic type T that will be instantiated. In your case type is ARInvoiceEntry
2. Call CreateInvoice Action.
3. This Action will instantiate a ARInvoiceEntry graph and insert ARTran records in that ARInvoiceEntry graph context.
4. Your hook will be called in the right ARInvoiceEntry graph context so it will handle ARTran insertion.